# Emacs : Ctrl+space (set mark) insert only a space in Konsole

Tags: emacs, kubuntu, konsole

I'm having a problem with emacs in Konsole : I can't set a mark to select text in emacs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> insert a space character instead of setting the mark.

On XTerm, I've almost the same behavior. It insert a tilde instead of the setting the mark.

Any idea on how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 3):

Ok I found what was the problem for me. IBus daemon had been configured to use the same shortcut. It can be changed by:

```
ibus-setup
```

and then restarting the daemon using something like:

```
killall ibus-daemon
ibus-daemon -d
```

Answer (score 1):

ESC-x describe-bindings

Will bring up your current bindings you probably have a second binding for set-mark-command,

```
Try Ctrl-@ INSTEAD.
```

Comment: Ctrl+@ works, C+SPC is already binded to set-mark-command.

Comment: I just updated to Kubuntu 14.04 and suddenly got the same problem. C+SPC is bound to set-mark-command but for some reason it's not working anymore. I tried to check if Kubuntu itself had bound it to something but I could not see that it did. (And also for me C-SPC stopped working in other apps too (Eclipse)).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix or work around this by explicitly setting up a keyboard sequence for control-space.  Under Settings → Edit current profile → Keyboard → Default (XFree 4) → Edit… I used the “+ Add” button and then added `Space+Ctrl` in the “Key Combination” field and `\x00` in the “Output” field.  Then I saved the new configuration and the control-space sequence was sent to Emacs.

If that hadn't worked I would have tried setting the “Output” to `\Exset-mark-command\n` to have control-space send the character sequence that Emacs would recognize as a specific request to run the `set-mark-command` function.